# Is there a work-around that allows missing data to equal NULL for LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a lot of large csv files with NULL values stored as `,,` (i.e., no entry). Using `LOAD DATA INFILE` makes these NULL values into zeros, even if I create the table with a string like `var DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL`. After a lot of searching I found that this is a [known "bug"](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23212), although it may be a feature for some users. Is there a way that I can fix this on the fly without pre-processing? These data are all numeric, so a zero value is very different from NULL.

Or if I have to do pre-processing, is there one that is most promising for dealing with tens of csv files of 100mb to 1gb? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal preprocessing with `sed`, you can have your data ready for import.

```
for csvfile in *.csv
do
    sed -i -e 's/^,/\\N,/' -e 's/,$/,\\N/' -e 's/,,/,\\N,/g' -e 's/,,/,\\N,/g' $csvfile
done
```

That should do an in-place edit of your CSV files and replace the blank values with `\N`. Update the glob, *.csv, to match your needs.

The reason there are two identical regular expressions matching `,,` is because I couldn't figure out another way to make it replace two consecutive blank values. E.g. `,,,`.

Comment: Thanks! How do I run this? My terminal-fu is pretty weak (I'm on Win7, but have cygwin installed).

Comment: Open a cygwin shell and go to the directory where your data is. You can then copy/paste the solution into the shell as long as the `*.csv` matches your dataset. Protip: make a backup of your data first! :)

Comment: Thanks. It's churning (on the copies)... I had no idea I could run for loops in the terminal.

Comment: +1 Snap! That does it. And not too bad on speed, either. I'm interested to see if there's an all-in-MySQL solution, but your's is hard to beat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"\N" (without quotes) in a data file signifies that the value should be null when the file is imported into MySQL.  Can you edit the files to replace ",," with ",\N,"?

Comment: +1 Good point. I could, but with all of these files it would be tedious. I am hoping to not end up there because most of the data providers in my research field provide NULL as an empty field instead of \N.